# Hirb doesn't work in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hirb

I have `hirb` in my Gemfile, bundle installed it, edited irbrc file according to the document I found online, even tried installing it from the console, but it still doesn't work. I also did `gem list` and know for a fact that `gem 'hirb'` is in there. I'm very new to being a programmer. Can anyone help? Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using mongoid?

Comment: I'm using ActiveRecord.

Comment: Did you do `require 'hirb'` & `Hirb.enable` ?

Comment: Yeah, I did. And it always returns the following: 
`[1] pry(main)> require 'hirb'`
`=> false`
`[2] pry(main)> Hirb.enable`
`=> true`
`[3] pry(main)>`

Comment: Then what did you run in your console to confirm hirb is not working? What output did you get?

Comment: I did `User.all` and it didn't come out pretty :(

Comment: Its hard to tell if you're not getting any errors. There is another gem called `awesome_print`, which does something similar, but not tabular display. You can use till you figure out what's the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've actually tried awesome_print too, but it didn't work. And this is what happened:
   `Successfully installed awesome_print-1.7.0
    Parsing documentation for awesome_print-1.7.0
    Installing ri documentation for awesome_print-1.7.0
    Done installing documentation for awesome_print after 0 seconds
    1 gem installed
    km-mbp13:slime km$ rails c
    Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
    [1] pry(main)> require 'awesome_print'
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- awesome_print`

Comment: I hope you've added it to your Gemfile and did a `bundle install`. Right?

Comment: Yup, I did that too.

Comment: Okay, you so you don't need to require `awesome_print`. You simple do `ap User.all`. I wonder what could be wrong.

Comment: Wow, I did that but not sure what that is, it showed a bunch of stuff.